# Use ApplySimple in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

​I have a problem and can't understand how create metrics.

​For example:
•​1/ Attribute [Net Weight] = 0,5 (type of data is decimal)
•​2/ Use function ApplySimple("Replace(#0,',','.')"; Max([Net Weight])) {Product}

​Could you please help me understand how to use function "ApplySimple".

Comment: (Sum(VOL) {~}  / Max(ApplySimple("replace(#0, ',', '.')"; [Net Weight])) {Product} )

Comment: I found it decision

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

(Sum(VOL) {~} / Max(ApplySimple("replace(#0, ',', '.')"; [Net Weight])) {Product} )

This metric divides the sum of VOL fact at report level by [Net Weight] after applying it a character replace at BBDD level with ORACLE's replace function (it seems that the BBDD is ORACLE), and breaks it down by product.

Splitting the fraction:

- Numerator: Sum(VOL) {~}
- Denominator: Max( ApplySimple("replace(#0, ',', '.')"; [Net Weight]) )

The #0 is the parameter's reference to apply the BBDD function, [Net Weight] in this case.

Regards!